# How to change the fields displayed if an instance is passed to a form?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a form something like this:

```py
class ExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Example
        fields = ('field1','field2')
```

Now, I want to add an additional field if an instance is passed to it. Which means that, if I create an form with an instance (for editing that object) I want to change the fields being displayed.

I know I can use create an another form for this purpose and create an instance of that rather than using this. However, is there a way to do this in this same form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `__init__` method, and modify `self.fields` when `instance` is passed to the form.

```
class ExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Example
        fields = ('field1','field2')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if kwargs.get('instance'):
            self.fields['field3'] = forms.CharField()
```

Comment: Is it possible to remove a field as well via this method?

Comment: You can try deleting a field with `del fields['field1']`. I can’t remember how that works if `field1` is in `fields`.